# Is it possible to COPY Gemfile.lock if it's in my .dockerignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

This is part of my Dockerfile

```html
FROM ruby:2.4.2

# throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

COPY Gemfile /app
COPY Gemfile.lock /app

RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --without development test
```

When I do docker-compose build, I get "COPY failed ... Gemfile.lock: no such file or directory"

But when I remove Gemfile.lock from .dockerignore, it works just fine.
I was told that I needed to have Gemfile.lock in .dockerignore, so is there any way around my error?

This is my .dockerignore

```html
.git
.dockerignore
Gemfile.lock
log/*
tmp/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the purpose of .dockerignore is just to tell docker daemon to ignore files during builds, so for docker there no Gemfile.lock in your folder when you run docker build.